# how to use port 8080 with ionic on a device

Tags: ionic-framework, port

I have an ionic app that uses an iframe. The CORS options from the server allow an origin of ionic://localhost:8080 and I cannot change this. However, ionic uses localhost:8100 by default.

Can anyone tell me how I can tell ionic to use port 8080 by default when I'm running my app on a device, so the iframe src url will be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ionic's docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve), it should be possible to do it like this:

```js
ionic serve --port 8080
```

Change it in your `package.json` for the `start` script and it should work as intended.

If you want to run it on your mobile device, according to the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run), it should also be possible to do it like this.

```
ionic cordova run android --port 8080
```

Comment: Ionic serve is for running an app in the browser. What I need is to be able to do is to use port 8080 while running the app on a device. Any ideas how to do that would be very welcome.

Comment: I edited my answer with an alternative. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks, but I realise now that I should have been more specific. What I need to do is to have the app run its internal web server on port 8080, even if I run the app from the icon on the home screen after installing it on a device, rather than running the app from the command line (I'm using Android Studio to run the app, so the cmd line won't work). That way, the the CORS headers that the backend server sends back will match the protocol, host and port, which will prevent the iframes from being blocked by the browser. If you or anyone knows how to do that, I will be all ears.